# Images from NSData Not Loading Correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to load images from `NSData` pulled from a server and display them in a custom `UITableViewCell`, but it is not working correctly and it is repeating the image over and over.

[image: Table View]

At the top we have `indexPath.row = 0`, going up from there. When the cell loads, it calls the following code to load the image (which when using NSLog returns the correct URL for every image), so it does seem to be downloading the correct image.

```
- (void) startLoadingImage
{
    NSString *url = @"myurlhere";
    url = [url stringByAppendingFormat:identifier];
    NSLog(@"Image URL: %@", url); //THIS IS WHERE I DETERMINE THAT IT IS DOWNLOADING THE CORRECT IMAGE
    NSURLRequest * request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSURLConnection * imageConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [imageConnection start];
}
```

When the `NSData` is returned from the server, the cell uses the delegate methods...

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if (!rawData) rawData=[[NSMutableData alloc]initWithLength:0];
    [rawData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Image did finish loading. Displaying...");

    [productImage setImage:[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:rawData]];
}
```

It works fine up to loading four images, and then it starts repeating the images (though the information in the cell like the name and price does show up correctly). This means that you would see the photo of the jeans over and over, every four cells.

Here is my `NSLog` output. Again, it looks like everything is correct.

```
2012-02-21 14:45:01.152 APPNAME[7873:11f03] Image URL: http://www.MYAPPURL.net/production/img/c_00084@2x.jpg
2012-02-21 14:45:01.173 APPNAME[7873:11f03] Image URL: http://www.MYAPPURL.net/production/img/c_00085@2x.jpg
2012-02-21 14:45:01.199 APPNAME[7873:11f03] Image did finish loading. Displaying...
2012-02-21 14:45:01.205 APPNAME[7873:11f03] Image did finish loading. Displaying...
2012-02-21 14:45:11.064 APPNAME[7873:11f03] Image URL: http://www.MYAPPURL.net/production/img/c_00086@2x.jpg
2012-02-21 14:45:11.476 APPNAME[7873:11f03] Image did finish loading. Displaying...
2012-02-21 14:45:12.432 APPNAME[7873:11f03] Image URL: http://www.MYAPPURL.net/production/img/c_00089@2x.jpg
2012-02-21 14:45:12.751 APPNAME[7873:11f03] Image URL: http://www.MYAPPURL.net/production/img/c_00080@2x.jpg
2012-02-21 14:45:13.010 APPNAME[7873:11f03] Image did finish loading. Displaying...
2012-02-21 14:45:13.013 APPNAME[7873:11f03] Image did finish loading. Displaying...
2012-02-21 14:45:14.574 APPNAME[7873:11f03] Image URL: http://www.MYAPPURL.net/production/img/c_00081@2x.jpg
2012-02-21 14:45:14.948 APPNAME[7873:11f03] Image did finish loading. Displaying...
```

So as you can see, it is loading images 84, 85, 86, 89, 80, 81, but it is only displaying images 84, 85, 86, 89, and then it repeats them.

Does anyone know why this is happening and why?

Comment: It looks like a cell reuse issue to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UITableView` reuses the `UITableViewCell` objects that you create (via the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method). You shouldn't modify the `UITableViewCell` objects directly. Instead, reload the table data and then update the cells in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.

In your view controller, you would have something like this:

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // set the product.image from the response data here

    // reload table
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Reloading data will refresh your table cells, which will call your delegate methods:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellId";

    UICustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        // create custom cell
        cell = [[[UICustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    Product *product = [products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = product.name;
    cell.image = product.image;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: And in fact, in the connectionDidFinishLoading, if you know the index path of the cell for which the image just finished loading, you can just reload the cell at that index path.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of your code, I think you might be having a problem with handling this as an asynchrounous connection. I don't see how you bind any particular cell to a connection request.

I think you might find the example in [Ray Wenderlich's Multithreading and Grand Central Dispatch on iOS for Beginners Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial) to be a very good fit for what you appear to be doing. I recomment that you look this example over carefully and see if you can make it work for you. YOu can download the sampel project (link near the bottom of that page) and see how it works yourself.